# the start of sports teams moving from the East to the West

Tags: expressions

> In 1946, Cleveland Rams moved to LA, **signifying the start of NFL
> teams moving west**.

Three questions here:

1. Is it okay if I use *"bespeak"* instead of *"signify"* in this sentence? I've looked them up in the dictionary to see if there's any difference in their meanings, but to no avail.
2. What I am trying to say here is that NFL teams started to move west after the year 1946 when a team from Ohio decided to move to the West coast. Based on the context provided, is it correct to say something like that?
3. I would like to know if there's a better way to express the meaning here, but I want to make it sound formal.

Comment: There's nothing informal about the use of "signifying", using "bespeaking" instead would just seem old fashioned (and pompous).

Comment: 'Bespeak' sounds worse than _pompous_ ... I'd say _farcical_.  A literary usage only now. // I'd use 'mark' here as a better fit than 'signify' (even though they _are_ pretty synonymous; it takes a lifetime to get a real feel for best choice hereabouts). // I find the whole structure a bit clunky. I'd use << In 1946, Cleveland Rams moved to LA, marking the start of a westward migration by NFL teams. >> The misplaced modifier usage is less abrupt, though some might still object, but they can be referred to the relevant Pullum article calling for the deportation of hyperprescriptivists.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Thank you for such a detailed answer! I really appreciate it. Now I know why the structure seems off to you. I agree your rework is a better way of expression, but I am also wondering if the sentence I wrote is grammatically correct? By the way, is it ok if I use "shift" in your sentence? I am trying to figure out the best choice of words here. Thanks!